# PLSQL Block fails with "into"

Tags: oracle, plsql

So I made this plsql block but I can't find why into fails

```
DECLARE
numero_llibres number := 0;
numero_pagines number :=0;
BEGIN
  select count(estat) into numero_llibres, sum(pagines) into numero_pagines from llibres where estat = 'pendent';
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('El numero de llibres que queden per llegir és'||numero_llibres);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('El numero de pàgines que falten per llegir és'||numero_pagines);
END;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax is:

```
SELECT column1, column2, ....
INTO   variable1, variable2, ...
FROM   ...
```

So your code should be:

```
DECLARE
  numero_llibres number;
  numero_pagines number;
BEGIN
  select count(estat), sum(pagines)
  into   numero_llibres, numero_pagines
  from   llibres
  where  estat = 'pendent';

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('El numero de llibres que queden per llegir és'||numero_llibres);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('El numero de pàgines que falten per llegir és'||numero_pagines);
END;
```